# bash: bash script gives Bad substitution error

Tags: bash

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

url=${cat /var/scripts/test.txt | grep -oP '(?<=display_url":")[^"]+'}

for url in $display_urls; do
    curl $url -O /tmp/$url.html
done
```

This bash script gives me Bad substitution error on Ubuntu. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
./script.sh: line 3: ${cat /var/scripts/test.txt | grep -oP '(?<=display_url":")[^"]+'}: bad substitution
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
url=$(cat /var/scripts/test.txt | grep -oP '(?<=display_url":")[^"]+')
```

That being said, to avoid [Useless Use Of Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#UUOC_(Useless_Use_Of_Cat)), try this:

```
url=$(grep -oP '(?<=display_url":")[^"]+' /var/scripts/test.txt)
```

From *man bash*:

> Command Substitution
>          Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace  the  command  name.
>          There are two forms:
>
> ```
>           $(command)
>    or
>           `command`
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`${VARIABLE}` is used for variable expansion and `$(command)` is used for command substitution.